# Djano:Solr rebuild_index error 403

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am in process of Learning in Django.

I have to build search engine for test application.

I have

> **search_indexes.py**

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Post

class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().published.all()`
```

And I created and set up Solr core admin for my application.

And when I try to execute `python manage.py rebuild_index` I get this error:

```
 raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
 pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 403): [Reason: None]
```

And also following response in *HTML* (this is just a part of response):

```html
<h1>This Page Cannot Be Displayed</h1>
<p>
Based on your organization's security policies, this web site( http://127.0.0.1/solr/blog/update/?commit=true )has been blocked because it has been determined to be a securitythreat to your computer or the organization's network.Access could also be blocked because this request came from anunrecognized or unauthorized machine.
</p>
<p>
If you have questions, please contactyour organization's network administrator and provide the codes shown below.</p>
</div>
```

I have "***blog***" application. I have `Post` model. I created in blog application directories blog/search/indexes/blog/post_text.txt

[image of blog core admin in solr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjm9n.png)

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Guys, The problem was my Proxy settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my Proxy settings.